# Using rename() but running into issues

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to rename a few columns, in use for a trading bot. For example:

```
df = stoch(df=df, high='High', low='Low', close='Close', fast_k_n=iParams['STOCHFASTLONG']['val'],
           slow_k_n=iParams['STOCHSLOWKLONG']['val'], slow_d_n=iParams['STOCHSLOWDLONG']['val'])
df = df.rename(columns={'slow_%kslong': 'slow_klong', 'slow_%dlong': 'slow_dlong'}, inplace=True)

df = stoch(df=df1, high='High', low='Low', close='Close', fast_k_n=iParams['STOCHFASTSHORT']['val'],
           slow_k_n=iParams['STOCHSLOWKSHORT']['val'], slow_d_n=iParams['STOCHSLOWDSHORT']['val'])
df = df.rename(columns={'slow_%kshort': 'slow_kshort', 'slow_%dshort': 'slow_dshort'}, inplace=False)
```

Basically what I am trying to do there is create two different stoch indicators, one will be used only for long with its own set of parameters, and the other for short. However what I did there doesn't work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why you are using `inplace` and assignment both? Use either one of them

Comment: I need to use both, not just one?

Comment: Use only `df.rename(columns={'slow_%kslong': 'slow_klong', 'slow_%dlong': 'slow_dlong'}, inplace=True)` . No need to assign it back to `df`

Comment: okay! silly me. works great now, thanks!